# Angular js subscribe multiple times and fire multiple events

Tags: angularjs, mediator

I am working for an application and I want to communicate Angular js with a third party js library. For this I have used pubsub method using mediator js. But due to this when I subscribe to any event then it subscribe multiple times and due to this when I publish event, it fires multiple times.

I have used below code:

```
angular.module('app')
   .service('mediator', function() {
     var mediator = window.mediator || new Mediator();
     return mediator;
 });

// Main controller begins here
  angular.module('app').controller('MainController', MainController);
  MainController.$inject = ['mediator'];

  function MainController(mediator){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "This is main controller."

    vm.sendMessage = function(){
      mediator.publish('something', { data: 'Some data' });  
    }


  }


  // First page controller begins here
   angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', FirstController);
  FirstController.$inject = ['mediator'];

  function FirstController(mediator){
    var vm = this;

    console.log('Subscribed events for first controller.');

    var counter = 0;
    mediator.subscribe('something', function(data){ 
      console.log('Fired event for '+ counter.toString());
      counter = counter + 1;
    });

  }
```

Here is the plunker for better explanation:
[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RLT6dwGaXJGY59Xra10G?p=info)

To test this plunker:

1. Run plunker.
2. Open developer console.
3. Click on First page
4. Click fire event
5. Click on second page
6. Click on first page
7. Click on fire event

As you navigate to first page second time, it will subscribe for event again and will fire twice. This will subscribe multiple time when you navigate to first page multiple times.

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: you are currently going to subscribe every time the controller is loaded, which will be every time you navigate to the page. This seems like a simple case of tracking if you are subscribed or not, and using an `if(!subscribed)` or similar.

Comment: Well, you're not unsubscribing when your controller is destroyed. So it keeps being subscribed. You not only have multiple console logs, but also a nice memory leak.

Comment: @JBNizet: Can you let us know, how to unsubscribe event using mediator js?

Comment: Note that angular scopes have a native event mechanism. f you used the standard $scope mechanism to broadcast and listen to events, angular would take care of that for you, because the $scope of a controller is destroyed with the controller.

Comment: But we ignore scope and rootscope and instead we are using viewmodel object (vm) for implementation.

Comment: just because you aren't actively injecting `$scope` for **variable properties** doesn't mean that it isn't in use internally by angular, or that you can't inject it when the need arises, like broadcast/emit.  The "`$scope` is bad" mantra is generally misunderstood, and not entirely true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unsubscribe when the controller is destroyed.

To do this using mediator, you first need to save subscription function:

```
var sub = function(data){ 
  console.log('Fired event for '+ counter.toString());
  counter = counter + 1;
}
mediator.subscribe('something', sub);
```

Then you can use the angular event to unsubscribe from the notifications when the controller is removed:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    mediator.remove("something", sub);
});
```

Whenever using this pattern, you should consider the moments when a subscription needs to be removed, not only for duplication reasons, but also it can cause memory leaks.

Don't forget you also need to inject $scope (even if not using it as a holder of model, it's fine to use it for registering event listeners):

```
angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', FirstController);
FirstController.$inject = ['mediator', '$scope'];
```

Plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/CgYLLSxGF2Fww5vBB7PB

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want to use $scope in my code. Is there any way out using view model object (vm)?

Comment: Why not? I'm not sure there is a straight-forward way to register listeners to VM events without $scope, as there is no direct way of watching for model changes without $scope. Again, even if you use the controller-as recommended pattern, there is still a scope behind which is managed by angular. $scope is perfectly fine to use for the things mentioned above.